# How can I make a customized search in windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

In windows 8, one could direct the search to a particular app and could get the results from that app.  But in windows 8.1, the smart search does not filter the result for a particular app. It includes search from the web which is OK, but not always convenient. Because some apps provide their own customized search, e.g. a dictionary app, which are not obtainable from smart search. How to overcome this?

for example, in Windows 8:

[image]

but in 8.1, we get this:

[image]

in this case how to get search results for **notes**, say, from **finance**? windows 8 allows to retrieve search results from **finance**.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8.1 the search have changed as you noticed - you can limit the search results by using the drop down:

[image]

What's missing here is Apps (to find apps) and a list of apps that can handle the old Search contract. Starting with Windows 8.1, you can only search within individual apps by launching the app in question and triggering search using some UI that's built into the app. So if you launch the Search charm from Mail, you can't search your email. You get the interface shown above.

Comment: @TomEus- As you point out this behavior change was done on purpose.  They wanted a uniformed experience dealing with search.  You lose a small amount of functionality but the programs that didn't have a search functionality didn't support the old behavior anyways.

Comment: @tomEus in pc settings->Search and apps->Defaults->chose default app by protocol, we see that almost every app is associated with a protocol. eg, the wordweb dictionary from the store is associated with `wordweb` protocol ( [scrshot](http://i.imgur.com/wwPomMh.jpg)). if we type this in browser (in FFox and IE) : `wordweb://?hello` wordweb launches and shows results for `hello` . So there should have been some way to do this in smart search,but there isn't. So tell me **can we do this type of search in smart search?** or if not, **how to bring back the old search contract** .

Comment: I will need to take a look at that but I don;t think you will be able to do it in the search dialog